# SQL statement: when all taks completed for a given ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have am querying an application in MS SQL server where I monitor when individual tasks are completed and I would like to query adding a column to identify if all individual tasks have been completed as shown below

```
tasks, completion_date, additional_column
task_1    15-Jan-17
task_1    
task_2    21-Jan-17      COMPLETE
task_2    06-Jan-17      COMPLETE
task_2    12-Dec-16      COMPLETE
task_3
task_3    21-Dec-16
```

Anyone can please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to use ANSI-standard window functions.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by task) = count(completion_date) over (partition by task)
             then 'Complete'
        end) as additional_column
from t;
```